# how do I pass on authentication tokens such as kerberos to Weblogic server through t3

Tags: java, weblogic, kerberos

I work on a project aiming to backport single-sign-on (SSO) to existing Weblogic/T3 based enterprise application. Ideally I would be able to utilize our Windows environment to perform this authentication using JAAS LoginContext and GSSAPI. This is unfortunately not documented for InitialContext provided by Weblogic (or at least I didn't find it yet) and it doesn't seem to have been explored by anyone else.

One idea is to authenticate to a Kerberos-realm (Microsoft Active Directory), pick the service ticket and pass it on through context environment. Custom IdentityAsserter is then required on the server side to extract and verify the service ticket.

Any ideas how to create and configure such IdentityAsserter? How to map the principal authenticated on a perimeter to application principal?

We have considered transforming the application to use http/https instead of t3/t3s but have no plans to follow that path, anticipating laborious tasks of redesign and associated test being somewhat out of the current project scope. As a consequence SPNEGO, servlet-filters, NegotiateIdentityAsserter and associated technologies will not provide us much help.

Comment: You wonder why Kerberos? Well, this will allow for propagating user's true identity all the way to the database. Although this maybe a real technical challenge by itself, it will ultimately allow us to apply complete access protection to the database schema.

Comment: No connection pooling? Right! We don't expect real performance issues as the application usage pattern shows rather low transaction frequency and database transaction times long enough to assume no real impact from connecting and disconnecting for each transaction.

Comment: Which DBMS? Any DBMS having decent, Kerberos-enabled, pure-Java JDBC-drivers will probably work. We do currently use Oracle with (I think) a bare minimum of stored procedures.